# Bootstrap Range: How to append bootstrap range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, append

I want to append the bootstrap range. The problem is javascript append is adding plain html elements only. It doesn't get the style using the $("#slide_add").slider({}); in jquery/javascript

**HTML:**

```
    <input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,5]" />

    <div id="range_added_section"></div>

    <input type="button" value="Add Range" class="add_range" >
```

**JAVASCRIPT APPEND:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#slide_default").slider({});

//ADD RANGE
$('body').on("click",".add_range",function(){

    $('#range_added_section').append
    (
        $(
            '<input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="5" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,5]" />'
         )
    );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Initialize `slider` after element is appended....`$("#slide_default").slider({});
$('body').on("click", ".add_range", function() {
  var elem = $('<input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,5]" />');
  $('#range_added_section').append(elem);
  elem.slider({});
});`

Comment: thanks @RayonDabre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAVASCRIPT: [SOLVED]**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#slide_default").slider({});
    //ADD RANGE
    $('body').on("click",".add_range",function(){

        var elem = $('<input id="slide_default" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,5]" />'); 

        $('#range_added_section').append(elem); elem.slider({});
    });

</script>
```